# Is a full list of requests made through/by my application through facebook easily available?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook asks that developers manage their app requests, and close ones that are no longer valid.

How do I get a list of all of the "applicationrequest"s made by my application (or through my application) from Facebook?

---

For background check out [facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), and I quote:

> It is the Developers' responsibility to delete a Request

Comment: Are you sure it is about "requests made by application"? Maybe it is about "requests for application IDs"?  - Link would be useful to figure out...

Comment: The relationship between an application and application id is not 1:1?

Comment: Normally people read "application" as "piece of code that does something". Yes, Facebook application 1:1 application ID, but your question reads "is there list of all request my code made to Facebook" which even if exists will unlikely be available without court order. Try provide a link (or paste the requirement for the Facebook site) for people to be able to answer.

Comment: Ah. Right. Applicationrequest is a technical term in facebook api world, which might not make sense to someone from outside. I'll find a doc link

Comment: +1. Makes sense now - from your link one can delete request after accept when ID is present, but yes getting list of all request may be useful. No idea how to do so.